# pystan .plot() plots trace summary twice

Tags: python, jupyter, stan

This is probably a stupid question, but whenever I'm using the .plot() function it plots the summary twice. Anyone knows, why it does that and how I can stop it?
[image: pystan.plot()]

As you can see I'm using jupyter notebooks if that matters.

It happens with any stan model (and on two separate installations)

This code would produce the problem for me

```
import pystan 
import numpy as np
model_string = """
data { 
    int<lower=0> N;
    int y[N]; 
}
parameters {
    real<lower=0, upper=1> theta;
}
model {
    theta ~ beta(1,1);
    y ~ bernoulli(theta);
}
"""
N = 50
z = 10
y = np.append(np.repeat(1, z), np.repeat(0, N - z))
dat = {'y':y,
      'N':N}

fit = pystan.stan(model_code=model_string, data=dat, iter=1000, warmup=200, thin=1, chains = 3)
fit.plot()
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working code? (and not just the line with plot)? Thank you

Comment: Added some code that produces the problem now

Comment: This doesn't happen to me on Linux. Do you have a ``%matplotlib inline`` somewhere? (I might also suggest posting this on the PyStan issue tracker: https://github.com/stan-dev/pystan/issues)

Comment: yeah, I forgot to include it in the code example. If I don't then no plots are showing. Thanks for the tip about the issue tracker, I'll post it there.

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by the `%matplotlib inline` statement drawing more than you want it to. The `StanFit4Model.plot` method calls `matplotlib.pyplot.subplot`, and that call itself will draw a plot when your notebook has `%matplotlib inline`. Then the method returns the `Figure` object. If you don't capture it, your notebook decides to show it to you as an image instead of printing the type, and you get the double plot.

You can output a single plot by capturing the output `Figure`. Change your code from

```
fit.plot()
```

to instead be

```
fig = fit.plot()
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting a semicolon after the `.plot()' also does the trick.

Learned it from https://github.com/stan-dev/pystan/issues/230